# how to check Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS is null in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to run a check as `if (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS == null)` however when I do get to this line, I get a null pointer exception. Now I know that there is no Documents Directory on the device I'm testing, so it should give me a null value and move into the block of code, but I want it to actually check it. I just gives an error.

My logcat shows:

```
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
 03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):    at com.example.testapp.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:640)
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:168)
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
 03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-18 11:11:24.667: E/AndroidRuntime(5183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How do I check (programmatically) if there is a documents directory on my device?

Answer (score 9):

Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS field is added in API Level 19.
So you can change the code as below to support for different versions:

```
File currentDir = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            currentDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS));
        }else{
            currentDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

As see here [Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) field is added in **API Level 19** *(Android 4.4(KITKAT))*

Make sure using API 19 for project and in `AndroidManifest.xml`